# como utilizar conceitos de dictionary select .value

Tags: c#, linq

o que significa esse select e .value

```
var idProdutosDistintos = DictionaryVendas
  .Select(x => x.Value.Produto.Codigo)
  .Distinct()
  .Count();

sw.WriteLine("E - " + idProdutosDistintos);
```

Answer (score 1):

O objeto que você está iterando é um `Dictionary`, que é um objeto do tipo *"key pair value"*, ou seja, um objeto que tem um par de dados, uma *"key"* que é a chave, e um *"value"*, que é o valor em si.

O `Select` vai interar sobre cada item dentro do seu dicionário, como se fosse um "loop", um *foreach* em cada item do dicionário, e o `.Value` vai obter o valor.

Esse `Select` pode ser substituido por algo como:

```
foreach(var item in DictionaryVendas)
{
    var valor = item.Value;
}
```

Mas note que o `Select` simplifica muito isso, tem outras operações que são executadas, tudo isso usando `Linq`.

Veja esse exemplo:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "SouKey", "SouValue" },
    { "SouOutraKey", "SouValue" },
};

var qtdNaoDuplicados = dic
    .Select(x => x.Value)   // "Seleciono" cada valor dentro de cada item ("x") do dicionário
    .Distinct()  // Removo duplicados
    .Count();  // Conto os itens

var value = dic
  .Select(x => x.Value)
  .FirstOrDefault();

var key = dic
  .Select(x => x.Key)
  .FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine("Value=" + value);
Console.WriteLine("Key=" + key);
Console.WriteLine("Quantide de valores não duplicados=" + qtdNaoDuplicados);
```

Aqui, usei o `FirstOfDefault` para pegar apenas o primeiro elemento e demonstrar. A variável `key` vai ter a chave, ou seja, "SomeKey", e a variável `value` vai ter o valor, ou seja "SouValue".

No seu caso, vai obter o objeto que está no value, uma objeto que tem a propriedade `Produto`.

A título de informação, o `Distinct` vai remover os duplicados, o `Count` contar quantos elementos tem.

Pode ver o exemplo acima funcionando aqui: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0J3aKZ